# How to info existing pods regarding new services in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In other words, how should we pass new env variables settings into existing pods?

Is re-creating the pods the only way to do so? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using service locations via environment variables is to run the [DNS add-on](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/dns/) in your cluster. It will make services become automatically discoverable both through A and SRV records.

Comment: Seems not fully function yet, but also seems to be the only alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by "not fully function[al| yet"?

Comment: check out known issues here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns#known-issues